# Left Join to the latest row using django

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I have two tables. 
Products [id, name, category]
Sales [product, date, price]

I want to get every Product with the latest row from Sales. If there is no row in sales, I still want to get that product row. The rows are foreign key related.

What is the Django way of doing such a left join?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? Its much easier to visualize what you want and help when you share your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you can use [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

sales = Sales.objects.filter(product=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')
products = Product.objects.annotate(latest_sale = Subquery(sales.values('price')[:1]))
```

Comment: This almost did it. It got me on the right track. Thanks. The part missing is products = Product.objects.all().annotate(latest_sale = Subquery(sales.values('price')[:1])) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

you can get the Sales object in view and render the object in template. for example you can do this.

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):

  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=100)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Sales(models.Model):

  product = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  price = models.IntegerField()
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.product.title
```

views.py

order_by(-date) gets you the latest item from the database

```
def sales_view(request):

   sales = Sales.objects.all().order_by(-date)

return render(request, 'template.html', {'sales':sales})
```

Now, in your template you can load the template.

```
{% for sale in sales %}

  {{sale.product.name}}
  {{sale.price}}
  {{sale.date}}

{% endfor %}
```

This way you get the product object even if there are no sales object. Hope you get some idea from it.